# Using 64bit ruby with 32bit ODBC driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, x86, odbc, 64-bit

I am planning to develop a rails application which has to connect to an database system for importing data. The ODBC driver which is provided is only 32bit.

Is it possible to use a 32bit ODBC driver within a 64bit environment or has the complete setup (os,ruby) to be 32 bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is impossible. If the driver is 32bit, the process communicating with the driver has to be 32bit too and the same for 64bit.

Sure there is no 64bit driver available?

Comment: There is a 64bit driver. But for a newer version. I have to connect to Gupta SQLBase 9.0.1. But when i tried to connect with this newer driver version i get an error. (http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=12604)